# Postfix and open port 25 but this port is not showed open with nmap

Tags: email, firewall, iptables, port

From the following post :

[Postfix issue : iptables rules and can't receive email from outside](https://superuser.com/questions/1118458/postfix-issue-iptables-rules-and-cant-receive-email-from-outside/1118460#1118460)

the solution suggested is working (can receive email from outside) but I don't understand why `nmap` (from outside on my `SMTP server`) doesn't show the port 25 opened, after applying the `iptables rule` to open this port. Indeed, I get with `nmap` :

```
Not shown: 994 closed ports
PORT    STATE    SERVICE
22/tcp  open     ssh
80/tcp  open     http
135/tcp filtered msrpc
139/tcp filtered netbios-ssn
443/tcp open     https
445/tcp filtered microsoft-ds
```

As you can see, `port 25` is not displayed as opened, are these results normal ?

Thanks

**UPDATE 1 :**

I apply the following rule (to immediately receive email from outside) :

```
iptables -I INPUT 5 -p tcp -m tcp --dport 25 -j ACCEPT
```

and it works just after applying this rule.

Then, with the result of `iptables -L` :

```
# iptables -L
Chain INPUT (policy DROP)
target     prot opt source               destination         
ACCEPT     tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere             tcp dpt:ssh
ACCEPT     all  --  anywhere             anywhere             state RELATED,ESTABLISHED
ACCEPT     all  --  anywhere             anywhere            
ACCEPT     tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere             tcp dpt:http
ACCEPT     tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere             tcp dpt:smtp
ACCEPT     tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere             tcp dpt:https
REJECT     tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere             reject-with tcp-reset
```

Then I do `nmap` and I get :

```
Not shown: 994 closed ports
PORT    STATE    SERVICE
22/tcp  open     ssh
80/tcp  open     http
135/tcp filtered msrpc
139/tcp filtered netbios-ssn
443/tcp open     https
445/tcp filtered microsoft-ds
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you can receive mail from the internet then port 25 should be visible in the nmap scan. You should post the output of iptables -L as well as the nmap command you used. Maybe you scanned the wrong IP address.